# How to capture a response token sent by a REST API after a request?

Tags: c#, rest, http-post, access-token

I am working on consuming a REST API and I am using basic authentication where password is encoded to Base64 as follows

```
 private XmlDocument sendXMLRequest(string requestXml)
    {
        string destinationUrl = "https://serviceapi.testgroup.com/testtp/query";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("API_TEST_NR:Testnol1$"));
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
        request.Method = "POST";

        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        //request.Connection = "keep-alive";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Timeout = 2000;
        request.MediaType = "text/xml";
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        Stream responseStream;

        using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(responseStream);

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(reader);


                try { reader.Close(); }
                catch { }
                try { responseStream.Close(); }
                catch { }
                try { response.Close(); }
                catch { }
                return xmlDoc;
            }
        }
        try { response.Close(); }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }
```

I'm kind of new to working on Web Api's and I know that the API responds with an access x-token after successful authorization based on the API documentaion and I am not sure how to access or capture it from the HTTP headers.

**May I know a good way I can achieve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easier than I thought just capturing with its name.

```
string xtoken= response.Headers["custom-header"];
Console.WriteLine(xtoken);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this as below, represents, Request Data Using the WebRequest Class.In most cases, the WebRequest class is sufficient to receive data. However, if you need to set protocol-specific properties, you must cast the WebRequest to the protocol-specific type. For example, to access the HTTP-specific properties of HttpWebRequest, cast the WebRequest to an HttpWebRequest reference.

```
private XmlDocument GetRootLevelServiceDocument(
string serviceEndPoint, string oAuthToken)
{
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
HttpWebRequest request = CreateHttpRequest(serviceEndPoint, 
    oAuthToken);

using (HttpWebResponse response = 
    (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (XmlReader reader = 
        XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream(), 
        new XmlReaderSettings() { CloseInput = true }))
    {
        xmlDoc.Load(reader);

        string data = ReadResponse(response);
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            LogMsg(string.Format("Error: {0}", data));
            LogMsg(string.Format(
                "Unexpected status code returned: {0}", 
                response.StatusCode));
        }
    }
}

return xmlDoc;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.